Checking the CallingConvention property of MethodInfo

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project and I am working on reflection. 
I tried to determine whether a class does not have a standard, non-static public getter. I have devised the code below:
    public static bool NotHavePublicGetter(  Type deger, string propertyName)
    {

        try
        {
            if (deger == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Type");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(typeof(string).ToString());

            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfoDizisi = deger.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            if (propertyInfoDizisi == null || !propertyInfoDizisi.Any())
                throw new InvalidOperationException("propertyInfoDizisi == null || !propertyInfoDizisi.Any()");

            MethodInfo getterMethodInfo = null;

            StringBuilder getDotNetName = new StringBuilder();
            getDotNetName.Append("get_");
            getDotNetName.Append(propertyName);

            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfoDizisi)
            {

                if (propertyInfo == null)
                    continue;                  

                getterMethodInfo = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod(false);
                
                if (getterMethodInfo == null)
                    continue;
                 
                // At this point, I need to check CallingConvention property of getterMethodInfo                    

                if (getDotNetName.ToString().Equals(getterMethodInfo.Name))
                    return false;

            }

            return true;

        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException hata)
        {
            //TODO productionda kalkacak. 
            //YAP2 testte aktive edilecek. 

            throw hata;

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException hata)
        {
            //TODO productionda kalkacak. 
            //YAP2 testte aktive edilecek. 

            throw hata;
        }
        catch (Exception hata)
        {
            //TODO productionda kalkacak. 
            //YAP2 testte aktive edilecek. 

            throw hata;
        }

        //TODO productionda aktive gelecek.
        //YAP2 testte deaktive edilecek. 

        //return true;

    }

During debug, CallingConvention property of getterMethodInfo is "Standard | HasThis". The problem here is that I cannot check getterMethodInfo property of "Standard | HasThis" . I tried "getterMethodInfo.CallingConvention == CallingConventions.Standard || getterMethodInfo.CallingConvention == CallingConventions.HasThis " but it returns false.
How can I check at the point that CallingConvention property of getterMethodInfo is "Standard | HasThis"? Thanks in advance.

Why do you think you can't just compare it to CallingConventions.Standard | CallingConventions.HasThis?

I've just write line "if(getterMethodInfo.CallingConvention == CallingConventions.Standard | CallingConventions.HasThis) continue;" and I am getting error "Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'CallingConventions'"

Operator precedence? Forgot some brackets?

If I'm blunt, if you not familiar with either flag enums nor operator precedence, I'm not sure you're ready to be writing a reflection-based framework for anything. If you have a mentor in your current organization, seek advice from them. If you're working alone, I'd suggest taking some more training on C#.

If I have a mentor in my current organisation, why should I ask this to StackOverflow?
